# Where are the grapsing package for ROS?

Tags: ros, grasp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know moveit provide it.
Is there any else?
I want to try more and compare.
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172721/where-are-the-grapsing-package-for-ros?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MoveIt is a motion planning framework not a full manipulation solution. That said,  I would recommend that you check out [moveit_grasps](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_grasps) as one option. Alternatively, I would recommend you look into GPD. There are a number of projects floating around that use that library with MoveIt including one from the [TAMS-group](https://github.com/TAMS-Group/moveit_gpd_pick_object) and a [ROS2 GPD + moveit project](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-grasp-library-moveit-intel-openvino-initial-release-0-4-0/8285) from Intel.

You may also want to explore [moveit_example_apps](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_example_apps) which has a pick and place application in it that uses MoveIt.

---

Originally posted by [mlautman](https://answers.ros.org/users/35816/mlautman/) with karma: 101 on 2019-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1